# Accessing directive attribute in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm new to angular and I'm using angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker, and I want to access its directive attribute data-datetimepicker-config in my controller

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '.dropdown-toggle' }"></datetimepicker>
```

I have a select component which contains values like daily monthly and yearly and I want to change the minView value of my datetimepicker with the select value.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that

> you can pass configuration options as a function or an object.

So you should simply define the config object in your scope or controller and then pass it as value of the `data-datetimepicker-config` attribute. Here's how you could go about it:

```
$scope.pickerConfig = { dropdownSelector: '.dropdown-toggle' };
```

Then in your view:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.date" data-datetimepicker-config="pickerConfig"></datetimepicker>
```

Basically, changes in `pickerConfig` will be applied to `datetimepicker` directive. It is as simple as that.